# Change start of chapters on left hand page with book documentclass

Tags: formatting, books

I would like for my PhD thesis to have chapters starting on the right hand side of the page, below a MWE. I have tried `\cleardoublepage` `\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}` w/ and w/o the additional `\mbox{}`...but nothing seems to work.

So far all chapters start on the left page.

Does someone know how to force the first page of the chapters to be on the right page?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}\mbox{}
\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}%this is done so that the ISBN are on the left page
A catalogue record is available from Utrecht University Library

ISBN: 
\include{Titlepage}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter1}
some text for chapter1
\end{document}
```

Comment: MWE = Minimal working example -- your example uses packages etc. that are not needed. And by default chapters start on the right page

Comment: I see the chapter starting on the logical page number 1, which is the 5th page in absolute numbers, so this is a recto page and as such, a right handed one

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  I have fixed the MWE, still I am asking because this is *not* the case for me. all chapters starts on a even page (left hand side) instead of an odd one. There are a couple of pages between the title and the table of contents (1 left and 1 right page). The table of contents starts on the left and adds a blank page at the end (with the header still quoting "CONTENTS" ) and then the chapters starts at page 10

Comment: Do you have a modified version of `book.cls` on your computer?

Comment: Not that I know of.. I am not such a LaTeX expert as to modify myself the .cls... I have seen in many threads that it is used **twopage** instead of **twoside**

Comment: ok, the twopage is a mistake many do, twoside is the correct option, but still it is not working for me...

Comment: Load package showframe, it helps you a lot. Also, did you mess around with page numbers? Many do and wonder why eft and right hand pages are messed.

Comment: FYI I was using the package `\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}`
for the quote in the page right before the `\tableofcontents`. Although it was easier to place the quote in the right spot and with the right formatting, this was giving problems with the `twoside,openright` options. I took out the package, I placed the quote where I wanted by means of white coloured text-lines  and everything is solved. I didn't think this could have something to do with the problem, therefore I didn't add it in my MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If run by itself the MWE (missing the file `Titepage.tex`that you didn't provide) comes out correctly with the TOC and Chapteer1 both starting correctly on a right-hand page. Thus, in all likelyhood you have some modified book class.

I added `\listfiles` in the preamble and that gives me the following log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./xx.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.15> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk12.clo)) (./xx.aux
(./Titlepage.aux)) [1{c:/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.
map}] [2]
No file Titlepage.tex.
(./xx.toc) [1] [2]
Chapter 1.
[1] (./xx.aux (./Titlepage.aux))

 *File List*
    book.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
    bk12.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 ***********

 )<c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><c:/tex
live/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><c:/texlive/2017/
texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsl12.pfb>
Output written on xx.pdf (5 pages, 32239 bytes).
```

You can see that there are 2 pages before not finding the Titlepage file, then two pages processing the TOC and then another one containing chapter 1.

So all as expected (and wanted).  So perhaps check what file versions you have for `book.cls` and `bk12.clo` and also whether they are picked up from a distribution directory (in my case `c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/`).

I realise that this isn't solving your problem, but I fear it can only be solved by you checking what differs in your installation from a standard setup.

Comment: I have found what the problem was (either conflit between `book documentclass` and `textpos package` or my incorrect use of the latter) . I upvoted all comments received and accepted your answer, so that the thread is closed.